# What does 'steeped with" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "steeped with" mean? I used this link: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/steep_2

> From the start, workers receive indoctrination into the BMW Way. They are **steeped with** a sense of place, history, and mission. Individuals from all strata of the corporation work elbow-to-elbow, creating informal networks where they can hatch even the most unorthodox ideas for making better Bimmers or boosting profits. The average BMW buyer may not know it, but he is driving a machine born of thousands of important brainstorming sessions. BMW, in fact, may be the chattiest company ever”(Edmondson, 2006, p. 2. Copyright2006. McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.).

Source: https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=iRArDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA259&lpg=PA259

Comment: From the page you linked “be steeped in something
(formal) to have a lot of a particular quality
a city steeped in history” It uses “in” instead of “ with” but it’s just slightly different wording.

Comment: There seems to be something really wrong with the markup of this question. It's making my browser show just white space with bits of text unless I move my cursor over it, at which point all the text appears (and then disappears again when I move my cursor away). It's affecting not just the question itself, but all of the answers. In the question, I see *chattiest company*, then a blank line with a square in the middle of it. I would edit the question, but I'm not confident enough to do so effectively in this case. (This is the only post on this site where I've seen this type of issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking various dictionaries, as the one you link seems somewhat limited.  "Steep" is also a verb:

> [**steep**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/steep) (v):
>       1. Soak (food or tea) in water or other liquid so as to extract its flavour or to soften it.
>       2. (usually *steeped in*) **Surround or fill with a quality or influence.**

Like the hot water around a tea bag, BMW workers become "flavored" with some influence that affects everything they do.

Comment: I would consider "steeped with" to be an error, just as I would "immersed with".

Answer (score 0):

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/steep) has this definition (an extract):

> **steep**
>   VERB
>
> **2** (usually **be steeped in**) Surround or fill with a quality or influence.
>
> *A city steeped in history*
>   *Your cuisine is steeped in the traditions of your family and the region*